# my picture after using tf.image.resize_images becomes horrible picture

Tags: tensorflow

1. **original_picture** (size:128*128) like this:

[image]

2. after using this function

   ```
   image = tf.image.resize_images(original_image,(128,128))
   ```
3. finally I use plt.imshow() to show my hand picture

[image]

Comment: This must be the cutest post on SO *ever*.

Answer (score 4):

The problem comes from [tensorflow's resize_images function returning floats](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize_images).

To properly resize and view the image you would need something like:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

with tf.Session() as sess:

    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    image = tf.image.resize_images(original_image,(128,128))
    # Cast image to np.uint8 so it can be properly viewed
    # eval() tensor to get numpy array.
    image = tf.cast(image, np.uint8).eval()

plt.imshow(image)
```

Answer (score 1):

The colours are inverted, i.e. each pixel's colour `[r, g, b]` is being displayed as `[255 - r, 255 - g, 255 - b]`.

This could have something to do with the data type of the image you obtain in step 2. Try the following after resizing the image:

```
image = image.astype(np.uint8)
```

Answer (score 0):

I will be using tensorflow library as tf.
tf.image.resize resizes the images(correctly) and then when we use plt.imshow on it .
But plt.imshow if it sees a float value be it .5 or 221.3 it clips that into the range[0,1].

---

Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1] for floats or [0..255] for integers).

---

This was the problem in my case ,

Original Image pixels[ 91 105 166] .

After resizing tf.Tensor([ 91.01 105.01 166.01], shape=(3,), dtype=float32)

You can see that the resizing is correct but the clipping is the one hurting .

To use the function properly .

```
img_resize = tf.image.resize(random_img,[250,250])
img_resize = tf.cast(img_resize,'int64')
plt.imshow(img_resize)
```

This should take care of the issues .